# Quotients of rings with finite free additive group

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a ring (assumed associative and unital) whose additive group is a finitely generated abelian group. As a reduction step in a paper I'm working on, we need to know that $R$ is a quotient of another ring $S$ whose additive group is a finite rank free abelian group. We believe we have a proof, but it is rather involved. Is this something that has appeared already or at least has a reasonably short proof? (The current proof reduces to showing it for finite rings and then proves it by using the basic ring associated to $R$.)

When $R$ is commutative, this has a quick proof: $R$ is generated by $r_1,\dots,r_n$ which are integral over ${\bf Z}$, and hence $R$ is a quotient of ${\bf Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f_1(x_1),\dots,f_n(x_n))$ where each $f_i$ is a monic univariate polynomial.

So I'm wondering if there is something analogous in the general case.

Comment: It may be good to say at the start that $R$ is "an associative ring" (with identity?) rather than just "a ring".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a finite ring $R$ you can write it as a quotient of the monoid ring $\mathbb ZR$ (with respect to the multiplicative structure) which has a finitely generated free additive group.

Comment: For the second part, I write $1=t+f$ where $t$ is torsion and $f$ belongs to the torsionfree part. Are you saying that $t$ is an idempotent? Could you please explain why?

Comment: If you square then since the torsion elements are an ideal you get $f^2=f$. Therefore $t=1-f$ is idempotent. I did forget to check it is central

Comment: It is clear $f$ commutes with torsion-free elements

Comment: I don't think this idempotent is central só I need a better trick to get to the finite case.

Comment: I still don't understand how you're getting $f^2=f$ (you're starting from $t+f = (t+f)^2$?). But here's another issue: $t$ could be 0, like in the ring whose additive group is ${\bf Z} \times {\bf Z}/2$ and whose multiplication is $(x,s)(y,t) = (xy,0)$.

Comment: Either way, doing the finite case was where our proof was more inefficient, so you've already helped trim the proof substantially with the monoid ring observation.

Comment: $t$ can be 0. That is true. But $f$ and $t$ are idempotent. If $f$ Is 0 this is clear.  Else $1=1^2=f^2+tf+ft+t^2$ and $tf+ft+t^2$ is torsion. So $f^2$ must be the torsion-free part of $1$. Thus $f^2=f$.

Comment: I see that the above argument is slightly off because $f^2$ could have a further torsion part.

Comment: I removed the mistake about idempotents

Comment: This works more generally when $(R,+\cdot)$ is generated as a ring by a finite submonoid of $(R,\cdot)$.